# How to center only one div inside a div and leave the rest as-is

Tags: html, css

The image inside `image-video-linkmas` has to be horizontally centered. I can achieve this by adding `text-align:center` to the div `.article`. However, then everything inside that is centered horizontally which I dont want. How to center the image and leave everything else as-is? I tried `.article .image-video-linkmas img {text-align:center}` but that didnt work.

```html
<div class="article">
        <article class="item single_masonary_item active">
            <div class="masonary_item_inner">
                <div class="image-video-linkmas">
                    <a href="" target="_blank"><img alt=
                    "#" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can just center the image with this:

```
img{
  display:block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

example:

http://codepen.io/nilestanner/pen/qaBjap

Answer (score 1):

There are actually many ways to go around this using CSS, but this is a personal favourite I use most of the time to center non-text things .

Ooh yeah I guess someone's already answered :) . I used in-line styling. Just manipulate the width until its the way you want

```html
<div class="article">
        <article class="item single_masonary_item active">
            <div class="masonary_item_inner">
                <div style='width:10%; margin:0px auto;' class="image-video-linkmas">
                    <a href="" target="_blank"><img alt=
                    "#" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
    </div>
```

Comment: It's not working for him though, and someone has put the exact same answer, your's is just inline code. Being aware of that, why would you copy his answer and put it in inline code?

Comment: And actually, your image is not completely centered.

Comment: hello there :) . if you can read, you would see that he put his answer whilst i was typing . And notice that i put a width :)

Comment: Oh never mind. You said that someone's already answered. My apologies +1 upvote.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

As @raulbaros said, his position is relative. To solve this problem, this should be your code.

```css
img {
  margin-left: 250px; /*you can modify this to according*/
                      /*to your likes it will make the  */
                      /*image look centered despite the */
                      /*relative property being applied */
}
```

```html
<div class="article">
  <article class="item single_masonary_item active">
    <div class="masonary_item_inner">
      <div class="image-video-linkmas">
        <a href="" target="_blank">
          <img alt="#" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

**BEFORE UPDATE**

Why can't you just put in your css...

```css
.image-video-linkmas {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="article">
  <article class="item single_masonary_item active">
    <div class="masonary_item_inner">
      <div class="image-video-linkmas">
        <a href="" target="_blank">
          <img alt="#" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: the problem is that `.image-video-linkmas` already has `position:relative` and `display:inline-block` for other effects I have, so `text-align:center` does not do anything.

Comment: I have fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

Use flex box to control the lay out. It is easy. Did not test since I am typing this answer inside the subway.

```html
<div class="article">
  <article class="item single_masonary_item active">
    <div class="masonary_item_inner">
      <div class="image-video-linkmas" style=" display: flex; justify-content: center"
        <a href="" target="_blank">
          <img alt="#" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```